# Distributing LWJGL launcher

Tags: java, lwjgl, launcher, software-distribution

I recently created a launcher for LWJGL programs which downloads the LWJGL JARs and natives, the Slick JAR, and the main JAR for the program (all configurable in the global variables), and I'd like to distribute it so that other devs may use it as a utility. However, I'm unsure as to where I would share it; the projects on LWJGL seem to be entire games, whereas my program is a 12 KB launcher. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Share it here [Java-Gaming.org/sharecode](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=80k0lioh74ksajd7arb3igu4v1&board=22.0) and just put utility in the Thread name.
Also could you post a link here as comment to the thread, so I could check it out and perhaps pass it on as well?